# link 200 worksheets in different wokbooks at once using vba

Tags: excel, vba

i have 2 workbooks and every workbook contain 200 sheets, i want to make link between for example cell E7 in sheet 1 in workbook1 and cell D3 in sheet1 in workbook2 and so on till sheet 200- the link is for the same cells E7& D3 - i want a code to loop between the sheets and paste special link instead of doing this manually one by one.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can create links to another Excel Workbook using worksheet formula as detailed in ( http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-HP010102338.aspx ): sample follows

```
=SUM('C:\Reports\[Budget.xlsx]Annual'!C10:C25)
```

You can automate the process of inserting the links using the `Range.Formula` with Excel VBA.
Hope this will help. Rgds,